# Is There an R Function that Automatically Fits the Best GARCH Model to a Time Series Data?

Tags: r, arima, quantitative-finance, volatility, fgarch

Just like we have the `auto.arima()` function of the `forecast` package in R that automatically fits the best `ARIMA` model to time series data, do we have the equivalent function that does that for a `GARCH` model? Take, for instance, simulated time series data as follows:

```
# simulate a time series data that follows `GARCH(1, 1)
set.seed(1234567)
garch11.sim <- garch.sim(alpha=c(0.02,0.05),beta=.9,n=500)
plot(garch11.sim,type='l',ylab=expression(r[t]),xlab='t')
```

[image: Plot given here]

**What I Need***

Is there any `R` function that can `automatically` select the best `GARCH` model for the series `garch11.sim`, just like a parody of the `auto.arima()` function?

```
auto.garch(garch11.sim)
```